# Where can I drill a hole in my Ford key?

Tags: ford, key

I have a key (for a 2006 Ford Focus), and the bit that attaches it to the keyring has broken off.

I could fix this by drilling a hole in it, and attaching the keyring to that. But it's got some electronic doodads inside it (so you can't just copy the key and start the car with it). Where is a safe place to drill a hole in it? Or how can I work out (without an x-ray machine) where it's safe to drill?!

[image: Key]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

this is a key that the transponder went out on, cut it down with a razor knife. the transponder is a black magnet looking thing, I have it marked in white.
as you can see, plenty of room on the upper for hole drilling

Answer (score 13):

Use some [Sugru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugru) on it

[image: Sugru'ed my alarm fob back together]

It's rubbery in consistency so it won't just snap off when you drop your keys. Use a piece of metal or plastic for the "crossbar" and sugru around it.

Comment: I added a link for those who don't know what Sugru is.  (I first thought it was a typo for "sugar" and got very confused.)

Answer (score 7):

Why not build up the back of the key with araldite [epoxy] and then drill that?

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but: Another option, if you can find one that fits, is a [rubber key cover](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubber%20key%20cover) that slips over the top of the key.

[Arbitrary example (not necessarily a fit for your key)](http://www.high-end-motorsports.com/ford-edge-keychain-key-remote-cover-ko.html):

[image]

These should work pretty well right out of the box and not require you to physically modify or repair your key.

Comment: I must add that this is a very neat solution. I'd prefer this over sugru or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

The cover should come off (for replacing the battery and whatnot), then you can drill a hole wherever you like with the electronics in full view.

Comment: No cover - no battery. I guess the transponder is something like RFID that doesn't need a power supply.

Comment: @JeremyMiles - That's exactly what it would be. There is a little chip in there which is energized by (usually) a ring which goes around the ignition switch, which then also reads the signal coming back from the transponder. Think of how the tags work at department stores when the detector goes off. No batteries there. The difference is, these have a unique and specific code which can be read from the computer when energized. If it matches what's stored in memory, the car starts. If not, the car won't stay running long if it starts at all.

Comment: So there's not even unlock/lock buttons on there? Lame!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I used a plastic suction cup, gold in half and super gluenit

Answer (score 1):

If you still have two working "CHIPPED" keys you can program a new third key.   I had to do this a few years back on one of our work trucks.
Buy a blank chip key, have it cut then follow the instructions in this link.  [FORD CHIP KEY Program](http://www.remotesremotes.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=F_80BIT-KEY)
If you get it right it works first time.
Then you can put the old broken one in the drawer as a back up.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a "clone" with just one chipped key. lt will work on that vehicle but cannot make more keys. 
 The trick is finding a locksmith to cut the key for you .  Most either want to sell you a overpriced key of theirs or have gotten yelled at for messing one up before.
 I had them cut me a key on a plain blank ( older Ford pu key) , walked outside and when it worked ; I went back in and said " You do a great job, now cut this one.  I understand the risks"